# Why does it say "metalled road"?

Tags: word-usage

Non-native English speaker here. Maybe this is easy for native speakers.

Wiktionary clearly explaines, that surfaced roads (covered in gravel, stones or tar) are refered to as [metalled](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/metalled) roads.

Why is metalled used as the overarching word?
This seems counter-intuitive since all of the stated materials used for the surface-cover are thoroughly non-metallic.

Comment: Since you are referencing Wiktionary, you might want to look at the noun "metal"...

Comment: Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Road_surface#Metalling (redirect from "metalled road")

Comment: In Australia at least, the crushed aggregate that roads are made out of (and other things you’d use aggregate for, like railways and gardens) is referred to as “bluemetal” (it is a dark bluish grey rock), so the noun form survives at least in part.

Comment: I'll note that I've never heard/read this term in the US (aside one or two instances in a British book written with a strong accent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the gravel surface entry on [Wikipedia's Road surface page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Road_surface) it

> refers to the broken stone or cinders used in the construction or repair of roads or railways,[42] and is derived from the Latin metallum, which means both "mine" and "quarry"

The first paragraph explains that

> Gravel is known to have been used extensively in the construction of roads by soldiers of the Roman Empire (see Roman road) but in 1998 a limestone-surfaced road, thought to date back to the Bronze Age, was found at Yarnton in Oxfordshire, Britain.[41] Applying gravel, or "**metalling**", has had two distinct usages in road surfacing. The term **road metal** refers to the broken stone or cinders used in the construction or repair of roads or railways,[42] and is derived from the Latin metallum, which means both "mine" and "quarry".[43] The term originally referred to the process of creating a gravel roadway. The route of the roadway would first be dug down several feet and, depending on local conditions, French drains may or may not have been added. Next, large stones were placed and compacted, followed by successive layers of smaller stones, until the road surface was composed of small stones compacted into a hard, durable surface. "**Road metal**" later became the name of stone chippings mixed with tar to form the road-surfacing material tarmac. A road of such material is called a "**metalled road**" in Britain, a "**paved road**" in Canada and the US, or a "**sealed road**" in parts of Canada, Australia and New Zealand.[44]